# Как из модуля ядра изменить привязку irq к процессорам?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Требуется после "захвата" прерывания с помощью devm_request_irq, изменить его привязку к процессорам.

Из консоли с соответствующими правами это сделать просто `echo 4 > /proc/irq/номер_irq/smp_affinity`

В ядре есть функция irq_set_affinity(unsigned int irq, const struct cpumask *cpumask); Но она не экспортирована и из модуля ядра не доступна. Кстати ФС `proc/irq` использует именно эту функцию.

Уточнение: ядро 3.17.

Обновлено:
Исходный код тестового модуля:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/irq.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Vasya Pupkin <vasya@pupkin.ru>");

int __init hello_init(void)
{
    printk( KERN_ALERT "Hello, world!\n" );
    irq_set_affinity(0, cpumask_of(1));
    return(0);
}

void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    printk ( KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, world!\n" );
}
```

Makefile

```
CURRENT := $(shell uname -r)
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

obj-m := test.o
test-objs := a.o

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Во время сборки получаем предупреждение `WARNING: "__irq_set_affinity" [/....../irq_set_affinity/test.ko] undefined!`
При попытке загрузить, получаем ошибку `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module test.ko: Unknown symbol in module`
в логах ядра dmesg `test: Unknown symbol __irq_set_affinity (err 0)`

Если закомментировать строку кода `irq_set_affinity(0, cpumask_of(1));` модуль успешно загружается.

Comment: а если просто с ядра открыть этот файл и записать туда 4? (точнее один символ)

Comment: *из модуля ядра не доступна* — [тут пишут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11863376/4827341), что доступна.

Comment: @KoVadim это костыль костылённый :)

Comment: @alexander barakin [определение функции](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/interrupt.h#L238), а вот [реализация](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/manage.c#L228) и функция не экспортируется посредством EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL.
При сборке моудя, линковщик выдаёт предупреждение на неизвестный символ __irq_set_affinity, а при попытке загрузки модуля, система выдаёт ошибку на тот же символ.
Всё проверено вдоль и поперёк.
Уточнение, ядро 3.17.

Comment: Непонятно, зачем это делать? Ядро предоставляет механизмы в user-space для собственного котроля (я, кстати, заметил, что большинство не понимает очевидной и простой вещи: user-space — **master**, kernel — **slave**!). Вот и используйте его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На днях попалась свежая статья [Делаем доступным все символы ядра Linux. - Олег Цилюрик](http://habrahabr.ru/post/267535/) 
Воспользовался его функцией:

```
static void* find_sym( const char *sym ) {  // find address kernel symbol sym 
   static unsigned long faddr = 0;          // static !!! 
   // ----------- nested functions are a GCC extension --------- 
   int symb_fn( void* data, const char* sym, struct module* mod, unsigned long addr ) { 
      if( 0 == strcmp( (char*)data, sym ) ) { 
         faddr = addr; 
         return 1; 
      } 
      else return 0; 
   }; 
   // -------------------------------------------------------- 
   kallsyms_on_each_symbol( symb_fn, (void*)sym ); 
   return (void*)faddr; 
}
```

Получил адрес не экспортируемого символа `__irq_set_affinity`, вызвал необходимую мне функцию, и все сработало!
Этот ХАК может не работать в будущих версиях GNU Linux. Но это проще, нежели рыться в дебрях структур данных ядра, отвечающих за необходимые мне состояния.

Выражаю благодарность автору статьи!

Comment: `static faddr` -- стремно как-то. Как Вы обеспечиваете "сериализацию" вызовов `find_sym()`?

Comment: Извините, не понял, что значит "сериализацию вызовов"?   В моём случае "стрёмность" допустима, код экспериментальный, да и условную компиляцию от версии ядра с предупреждениями/ошибками всегда можно применить.

Comment: Сериализация -- ну, в данном случае я имел в виду, что следующий вызов не произойдет ранее return от предыдущего (прерывания, разные thread ... и версии ядра тут вообще не при чем). Т.е. меня на самом деле заинтересовало, static тут -- это обязательно? И если да, то почему. Кстати, для того чтобы я увидел, что появился новый комментарий надо в нем меня (@avp) упомянуть (а Вас (поскольку автор ответа) необязательно)... Такая вот дурь.

Comment: Кстати, обратили внимание на `mm_segment_t fs = get_fs(); 
      set_fs( get_ds() ); 
      n = sys_write( 1, buf, len ); 
      set_fs( fs );` в статье?

Comment: @avp забываю про функцию упоминания, не часто комментарии пишу. Статью только вчера прочитал, поэтому отвечать за автора не могу. Как понимаю static не обязателен, видимо используется чтоб "символами не светить", где-то в статье у него про это говориться. В любом случае "контекст" в виде структуры можно передавать в функцию снаружи. Для моего случая однократного использования, при инициализации модуля, и такое решение сойдёт.

Comment: Это, конечно. При инициализации сойдет. Просто стало интересно, зря там (в статье) !!! в комментарии для static или нет.